# How to get folder thumbnail with alpha channel

Tags: shell, bitmap

There is a nice feature in windows - thumbnail view. So we can see not just folder icon but also small parts of thumbnails of files in the folder.  When I tried to get a thumbnail, I got the following:
[screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/38515377d7.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/38515377d7.jpg)

C#, Shell api -> native bitmaps -> wpf bitmap(i think this part is not important)

Answer (score 0):

It is decided by the thumbnail provider currently registered with the file format on the user's system. You can not predict which thumbnail provider would be installed on the client's computer.

I suggest you check the format of the result thumbnail to see if it has the alpha channel.